# Using JQuery to parse out element tags but not its contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string that contains html and I want to remove the entire span element but not its contents from the string (I want to leave the word Canadian and any other elements).

```
var htmlString = 
<p>The Royal <span class="highlight-keyword highlight-keyword-2 highlight-pid-28" style="font-weight: bold;">Canadian<span> Navy  (RCN) is the naval force of Canada.<p> 
<p>As of 2015 <span class="highlight-keyword highlight-keyword-2 highlight-pid-28" style="font-weight: bold;">Canada's</span> navy operates 1 destroyer, 12 frigates, 4 patrol submarines, 12 coastal defence vessels and 8 unarmed patrol/training vessels, as well as several auxiliary vessels.</p>
```

Now if I was manipulating the DOM I could simply use

```
$(this).find("span.highlight-keyword").each(function () {
     $(this).contents.unwrap();
})
```

But I am not manipulating the DOM I am manipulating a string and I want to return the entire string without the span element but keeping everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code:**

```
var htmlString = "<p>The Royal <span class='highlight-keyword highlight-keyword-2 highlight-pid-28' style='font-weight: bold;'>Canadian<span> Navy  (RCN) is the naval force of Canada.<p><p>As of 2015 <span class='highlight-keyword highlight-keyword-2 highlight-pid-28' style='font-weight: bold;'>Canada's</span> navy operates 1 destroyer, 12 frigates, 4 patrol submarines, 12 coastal defence vessels and 8 unarmed patrol/training vessels, as well as several auxiliary vessels.</p>"

var cleanString = $(htmlString).find('span').each(function() {
  $(this).contents().unwrap();
}).end().appendTo('<div/>').parent().html();

console.log(cleanString)
```

**Sample:**

https://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/5a23stwq/

**Steps:**

1. Create jQuery object from HTML.
2. For each span unwrap the contents.
3. Call end() to return original jQuery object NOT spans that were previously filtered.
4. Call AppendTo temporary object which will now be the parent however is never attached to the DOM
5. Return html() function off the temp object as parent.

**Results from console:**

```
<p>The Royal Canadian Navy  (RCN) is the naval force of Canada.</p><p></p><p>As of 2015 Canada's navy operates 1 destroyer, 12 frigates, 4 patrol submarines, 12 coastal defence vessels and 8 unarmed patrol/training vessels, as well as several auxiliary vessels.</p>
```

Comment: Clean, simple and does exactly what I need it to do! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to create temporary dom node, set html into this node,  remove span, and get `innerHTML`.

But if you want to do this hard way.

You can try to match everything from string except span nodes.

```
var htmlString = `
<p>The Royal <span class="highlight-keyword highlight-keyword-2 highlight-pid-28" style="font-weight: bold;">Canadian<span> Navy  (RCN) is the naval force of Canada.<p> 
<p>As of 2015 <span class="highlight-keyword highlight-keyword-2 highlight-pid-28" style="font-weight: bold;">Canada's</span> navy operates 1 destroyer, 12 frigates, 4 patrol submarines, 12 coastal defence vessels and 8 unarmed patrol/training vessels, as well as several auxiliary vessels.</p>`

htmlString.split('\n')
     .filter(x=>x)
     .map( str => str.match( /(.+)(?:<span[^>]*>)(.*)(?:<\/?span>)(.*)/ ).slice(1).join('')  )
     .join('\n')
```

I was too lazy to filter special characters in your text, so i used es6 template string syntax.

Comment: Fixed bug, not matching second span tag in first row.

Comment: My bad I should have mentioned that regex wouldn't work as the class names will sometimes be different i.e. highlight-keyword-2, highlight-keyword-3. It appears that creating a temporary dom node was the way to go after all as Sean mentioned in his answer.

Comment: Regex dons't use any class name, it just removes span tags (all of them). But anyway, using regex for this task is kinda esoteric or jokingly way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.prototype.replace` with regex to remove the `span` elements:

```js
var htmlString = '<p>The Royal <span class="highlight-keyword highlight-keyword-2 highlight-pid-28" style="font-weight: bold;">Canadian<span> Navy (RCN) is the naval force of Canada.</p> <p>As of 2015 <span class="highlight-keyword highlight-keyword-2 highlight-pid-28" style="font-weight: bold;">Canada\'s</span> navy operates 1 destroyer, 12 frigates, 4 patrol submarines, 12 coastal defence vessels and 8 unarmed patrol/training vessels, as well as several auxiliary vessels.</p>';

var withoutSpans = htmlString.replace(/<\/?span[^>]*>/ig, '');

console.log(withoutSpans);
```